# Replace space between a letter and a number with a comma?

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to replace the spaces between the city and the number with a comma, but the line I came up with (and variations of it) seem to obliterate the string.

```
>>> temp = re.sub(r"(\w+).*?(\d+)", ",", string)
```

where `string` is like:

```
Toronto 239495
Cape Town 34567
```

How can I do this?

*I'm still picking up regex, so any explanations with any code would be really great.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're replacing the right matches, but only with a comma! The other parts of the match get replaced too. You could use assertions, or just stick them back in:

```
temp = re.sub(r"(\w+).*?(\d+)", r"\1,\2", string)
```

However, the `\w+` will only match the `Cape` in `Cape Town`. How about:

```
temp = re.sub(r"(.+?)\s*(\d+)", r"\1,\2", string)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [lookbehind and a lookahead](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
In [1]: s = 'Toronto 239495 Cape Town 34567'

In [2]: re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\s(?=\d+)", ",", s)
Out[2]: 'Toronto,239495 Cape Town,34567'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In  [1]: string = "Toronto 239495 Cape Town 34567"

In  [2]: re.sub(r"(\w)\s+(\d)", r"\1,\2", string)
Out [2]: 'Toronto,239495 Cape Town,34567'
```

There's no reason to match the whole name of the city in this case. This just matches a letter followed by at least one space, followed by a digit. It then replaces the spaces with a single comma.